# Integrating batch commit and cloud firestore triggers

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a batch commit of documents in chunks of 50 to cloud firestore collection named 'Activities' and i have written a cloud function which gets triggered on create, update and delete of any document in that collection but the cloud function gets triggered only one time for each batch not for all documents in the batch.

I have counted the logs which prints how many times the cloud functions is called and it is roughly matching to the number of times batch commit has been called.

Code that is executing batch commit :

```
    const activitiesRef = app.firestore.collection(`activities`);
    if (_.isArray(insertObj)) {
        const chunksOf450 = await _.chunk(insertObj, 450);

        for (const singleChunk of chunksOf450) {
            // Get a new write batch
            const batch = app.firestore.batch();
            for (const obj of singleChunk) {
                const tempRef = activitiesRef.doc((obj as any).uid);
                batch.set(tempRef, obj);
            }

            // Commit the batch
            await batch.commit();
        }

        return {
            message: 'All objects written to database successfully'
        };
```

Cloud Function which gets triggered on onWrite :

```
export default functions.firestore.document('activities/{activityId}').onWrite(async (snap, context) => {
const isDocumentExists = snap.after.exists

utils.app.initializeApp(initializeAdminApp.default);
adminUtils.ElasticHelper.init();


if (isDocumentExists) {

    const afterDocData = snap.after.data();
    const afterDocId = snap.after.id;

    console.log('starting..', afterDocData, afterDocId);



    const { contentType } = snap.after.data();

    if (contentType === 'activityTypes') {
        await adminUtils.ElasticHelper.index('activity', afterDocId, afterDocData);
    }
    if (contentType === 'itemTypes') {
        await adminUtils.ElasticHelper.index('item', afterDocId, afterDocData);
    }
    if (contentType === 'questionTypes') {
        await adminUtils.ElasticHelper.index('question', afterDocId, afterDocData);
    }

} else {
    const beforeDocId = snap.before.id;
    const { contentType } = snap.before.data();

    console.log('deleting on elastic ..', beforeDocId);

    if (contentType === 'activityTypes') {
        await adminUtils.ElasticHelper.delete('activity', beforeDocId);
    }
    if (contentType === 'itemTypes') {
        await adminUtils.ElasticHelper.delete('item', beforeDocId);
    }
    if (contentType === 'questionTypes') {
        await adminUtils.ElasticHelper.delete('question', beforeDocId);
    }
}
console.log('function success');
});
```

For each document that gets written in batch commit i want this cloud function to get triggered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you delete the collection entirely and then do the batch commit because if the collection already exists and you try to overwrite the documents, the cloud triggers wont start. You have to delete all documents first.